# Sending a serialized object from Android to a servlet using HTTP client

Tags: java, android, serialization, httpclient

I have tried to create a android application that sends a serialzed object from the phone to a servlet the contents of the object is the input from the user which i will store in a database using hibernate. I believe the problem is around the serializing and deserializing of the object the code is below. If anyone could help i would very greatful.

p.s the class User implements the serializable interface

client

```
    public class Adduser extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

 EditText uname;
 EditText password;
 EditText rating;
 EditText date;
 Button add;
 User user;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Usernamei);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordi);
        rating = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ratingi);
        date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.datei);
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Adduser);

        user = new User();



        add.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {

  user.setusername(uname.getText().toString());
        user.setpassword(password.getText().toString());
        user.setdate(date.getText().toString());
        user.setrating(rating.getText().toString());

  HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  ObjectOutput out;

  try{
    String url = "MY URL goes here";

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);


    //Serialisation of object
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream() ;
       out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos) ;
       out.writeObject(user);

       //puts bytes into object which is the body of the http request
       post.setHeader(new BasicHeader("Content-Length", "" + bos.toByteArray().length));

       ByteArrayEntity barr = new ByteArrayEntity(bos.toByteArray()); 
       //sets the body of the request 
       post.setEntity(barr);

       out.close();
       //executes request and returns a response
       HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post); 

  } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e( "ouch", "!!! IOException " + e.getMessage() );
     }

  uname.setText(String.valueOf(""));
  password.setText(String.valueOf(""));
  rating.setText(String.valueOf(""));
  date.setText(String.valueOf(""));

 }
}



Server side

    public class Adduser extends HttpServlet {

 //logger for properties file
 //private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Adduser.class);



 public void doPost (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException {
  //test
  //logger.warn("this is a sample log message.");


  String usern = null;
  String password = null;
  String rating = null;
  String date = null;

  InputStream in;
  try {
   //gets http content body byte array should be on the stream
   in = request.getInputStream();

   //int bytesToRead;
   //bytesToRead =  Integer.parseInt(request.getHeader("Content-Length"));


   //reads inputream contents into bytearray
   int bytesRead=0;
   int bytesToRead=1024;
   byte[] input = new byte[bytesToRead];
   while (bytesRead < bytesToRead) {
     int result = in.read(input, bytesRead, bytesToRead - bytesRead);
     if (result == -1) break;
     bytesRead += result;
   }



   //passes byte array is passed into objectinput stream 
   ObjectInputStream inn = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(input));
   User users = null;
   try {
    //object is read into user object and cast
    users = (User)inn.readObject();
   } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    System.out.println(e1.getMessage());

   }
   in.close();
   inn.close();

   //contents of object is put into variables to be passed into database
   usern = users.getusername();
   password = users.getpassword();
   rating = users.getrating();
   date = users.getdate();

  } catch (IOException e2) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   System.out.println(e2.getMessage());
  }




  Session session = null;

  try{
   SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory(); 
   session = sessionFactory.openSession();
          //Create new instance of Contact and set 
   Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

      Userr user = new Userr();
      user.setusername(usern);
      user.setpassword(password);
      user.setrating(rating);
      user.setdate(date);
      session.save(user);

      tx.commit();
  }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      }finally{
        // Actual contact insertion will happen at this step

        session.flush();
        session.close();

        }

 }




 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested, use XML or JSON.
You can get [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) patched for Android [from this blog](http://jars.de/java/android-xml-serialization-with-xstream) in order to serialize your objects to XML.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use serialization between architectures. Use JSON, XML, or something else that is architecture-neutral.

Comment: why does it need to be architecture neutral if the OP is controlling the servlet?

Comment: @Rick: The servlet is not the problem. Clients are the problem. Right now, the OP is strictly thinking of Android. First, there is no guarantee that the serialization format for Android is the same as for the server, since they are not running the same runtime. Second, serialization can only possibly work with a Java-ish client, eliminating iOS, Windows Phone, Symbian, Javascript (WebOS, AJAX/HTML5), Flash, or any non-Java desktop environment. Smart programmers box themselves in as few corners as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I second the suggestion of XStream. It is a very nice and easy API. I don't like the Serialization formats XML or JSON though because they are text based. For a more compact serialization format, try [ProtoBuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) from Google.