# How to pass an Array of Objects in HTTP Post Request in Android?

Tags: android

I want to pass List of Objects, say Drivers, in HTTP POST Request. While NameValuePair takes only Strings. How I can pass it with HTTP POST Request?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
StringEntity ss= new StringEntity(yourObj.toString());
        // Set HTTP parameters
        httpPost.setEntity(se);
```

I think it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

i think this post will be helpful to you

[Sending a serialized object from Android to a servlet using HTTP client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009707/sending-a-serialized-object-from-android-to-a-servlet-using-http-client)

they suggests to use JSON or XML